# C#: Can I minimize app in BackgroundWorker running & update UI

Tags: c#, user-interface, backgroundworker

I have a backgroundWorker thread running. At the end I update the UI, minimize the app & change the icon.

I tried to minimize the app in middle, but then the UI wasn't updated, nor the icon was changed. Thread was executed but this part wasn't done.

Can't the UI get updated when the app is minimized ? If can, where I may be going wrong.

UPDATED :

@Daniel, YesI am aware of it. And when the task is done I call ProgressChanged is called and finally RunWorkerCompleted is also called. BUT when I minimize the app in middle, the components like Label's aren't changed. Button text is changed, but it hangs/stucks - button doesn't work any longer. MY point is : If app is minimized during executing DoWork, then when ProgresChanged & RunCompleted is called or not. If called then why certain components aren't changed. NOTE: If I don't minimize in middle, then everything works perfectly fine.

Comment: please show some source code... otherwise an answer is pure speculation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only update the UI from the UI thread. The [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) and [`RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) events are run on the UI thread, the [`DoWork`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) event is not. This means, if you want to update your UI from a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) while it is running, you need to do it in the `ProgressChanged` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using WPF or Winforms ? 
In any case, if you want to do something with the UI, you will have to come back into the UI thread.

To do so, in WPF, you can use the dispatcher object, and invoke on it, so the method will be executed by the UI thread, and not by your worker thread. 
In Winforms, you will have to maintain a reference to some UI control, and invoke on this control.

Consider the following code snippet (WPF) :

```
    if (!myCheckBox.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
  myCheckBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new Action(
      delegate()
      {
        myCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
      }
  ));
}
else
{
  myCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
}
```

Here is another code snippet I use in Winforms, to raise my events from my UI thread

```
Friend Shared Sub RaiseUiEvent(ByVal hnd As EventHandler, ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim uiRef = GlobalManager.GetInstance().UI

    Try
        uiRef.BeginInvoke(hnd, sender, e)

    Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
        ''if UiRef is null, then we simply drop the event
        Logger.AddTextToLog(ex)
        Debug.WriteLine("Invalid operation in raiseUiEvent")
    Catch ex As NullReferenceException
        Logger.AddTextToLog(ex)
        Debug.WriteLine("Null Reference in RaiseUiEvents")
    End Try
End Sub
```